# Q about static configuration of javascript/css URL?

Tags: javascript, css, html, dojo

I have a single page web application that utilizes DOJO (1.9.x). It normally loads the DOJO library from the Google CDN and my application functions as expected. But, some customers offer limited internet connection that excludes most of the internet for security (!?) reasons. So I have to host DOJO library locally on the server.

For this to work, I should point the URL to the local copy of dojo.js and relevant CSS files. As only the prefix of the URL changes, I am curious if there is a trick to achieve this by some external CSS file so that the URL in the HTML gets its prefix from this small CSS. By simply editing/changing this small CSS file, One site will load DOJO from the Google CDN and Another will load the locally hosted DOJO.

Is this possible with a static CSS file ?

Comment: Huh? You want to change a part of a URL by using CSS? Do you know what CSS stands for?

Comment: @Dimitri: I do not want to edit HTML. JS is the target to load. Only CSS is left as an option. As CSS is so complex, I thought there was a way. There are hacks like http://css.dzone.com/articles/executing-javascript-inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS.

A few alternatives, in order of preference:

1. SAFEST - Distribute two versions of the page/app, with local and remote dojo.
2. If you have server-side rendering of any sort, configure that to update the dojo URL.
3. Always distribute the dojo loader with your application.  Thereafter, load dojo modules from CDN or locally according to your config.  This could get hairy.

More details on option 3:

dojoConfig.js

```
//var dojoRoot = ".."; // For LOCAL builds - relative to dojo.js
var dojoRoot = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3"; // For CDN builds

var dojoConfig = {
    packages: [
        // Depending on your project structure, you may need to 
        // insert entries here for your local packages.

        // Here, we override the location for dojo packages
        {
            name: "dojo",
            location: dojoRoot + "/dojo"
        },
        {
            name: "dojox",
            location: dojoRoot + "/dojox"
        },
        {
            name: "dijit",
            location: dojoRoot + "/dijit"
        }
    ]
};
```

HTML snippet to use it

```
<script src="dojoConfig.js"></script>
<script src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
    require(["dojo/_base/config", "dojo/json"], function(config, JSON) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(config.packages, null, "\t"));
    });
</script>
```